# Is it possible to join a table with itself twice? (Using SQLAlchemy or SQL)

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a following model in SQLAlchemy:

```py
    class SomeEvent(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
        created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime())
        type = db.Column(db.String(20))
        event_target = db.Column(db.String(10))
        group = db.Column(db.String(20))
```

Is there any way to produce a query that will return a result consisting of all records of one type + records of two other types (if these two records have same event_target else just records of a single type) of the same group ordered by `created_on` date?

What I've managed to come up with:

```py
        Single_type_event = aliased(SomeEvent)
        Paired_type_event_1 = aliased(SomeEvent)
        Paired_type_event_2 = aliased(SomeEvent)

        columns = [
            Single_type_event.id.label('single_type_event_id'),
            Single_type_event.type.label('single_type_event_type'),
            Single_type_event.event_target.label('single_type_event_target'),
            Paired_type_event_1.id.label('paired_type_event_1_id'),
            Paired_type_event_1.type.label('paired_type_event_1_type'),
            Paired_type_event_1.event_target.label('paired_type_event_1_target'),
            Paired_type_event_2.id.label('paired_type_event_2_id'),
            Paired_type_event_2.type.label('paired_type_event_2_type'),
            Paired_type_event_2.event_target.label('paired_type_event_2_target'),
        ]

        query = (db.session.query(*columns)
                .outerjoin(SomeEvent, (
                    (SomeEvent.group == 'some_group') & 
                    (SomeEvent.id == Single_type_event.id) |
                    (SomeEvent.id == Paired_type_event_1.id) |
                    (SomeEvent.id == Paired_type_event_2.id)
                ))
                .outerjoin(Single_type_event, (
                    (SomeEvent.id == Single_type_event.id) &
                    (SomeEvent.event_target == Single_type_event.event_target) &
                    (SomeEvent.type == 'type_1')
                ))
                .outerjoin(Paired_type_event_1, (
                    (SomeEvent.id == Paired_type_event_1.id) &
                    (SomeEvent.event_target == Paired_type_event_1.event_target) &
                    (SomeEvent.type == 'type_2')
                ))
                .outerjoin(Paired_type_event_2, (
                    (SomeEvent.id == Paired_type_event_2.id) &
                    (SomeEvent.event_target == Paired_type_event_2.event_target) &
                    (SomeEvent.type == 'type_3')
                ))
                .order_by(SomeEvent.created_on.asc())
        )
```

But of course it doesn't work, because I'm lacking the understanding of how to do this right, if it's even possible =(

Example of the query results that I would like to achieve(`._asdict()` applied):

1. If a record with a given `event_target` has `type == 'type_1'`:

```py
    {'single_type_event_id': 'some_id',
    'single_type_event_type': 'type_1',
    'single_type_event_target': 'target_1',
    'paired_type_event_1_id': None,
    'paired_type_event_1_type': None,
    'paired_type_event_1_target': None,
    'paired_type_event_2_id': None,
    'paired_type_event_2_type': None,
    'paired_type_event_2_target': None}
```

2. If there is only a record with `type == 'type_2'` for a given `event_target` (still it could have a `type_1` record earlier but it should be in a distinct row like the one before):

```py
    {'single_type_event_id': None,
    'single_type_event_type': None,
    'single_type_event_target': None,
    'paired_type_event_1_id': 'some_id',
    'paired_type_event_1_type': 'type_2',
    'paired_type_event_1_target': 'target_1',
    'paired_type_event_2_id': None,
    'paired_type_event_2_type': None,
    'paired_type_event_2_target': None}
```

3. And, finally, if there are records of both event types for a given `event_target` (there shouldn't be distinct rows for each type - only this combined one):

```py
    {'single_type_event_id': None,
    'single_type_event_type': None,
    'single_type_event_target': None,
    'paired_type_event_1_id': 'some_id_1',
    'paired_type_event_1_type': 'type_2',
    'paired_type_event_1_target': 'target_1',
    'paired_type_event_2_id': 'some_id_2',
    'paired_type_event_2_type': 'type_3',
    'paired_type_event_2_target': 'target_1'}
```

I would like to have all these results having the same group and ordered by created_on (for the last example it should be ordered by the `paired_type_event_1` date).

An abstract example:
a `person_1`(`event_target`) is living in a `town_a`(`group`). He has a record of when he was born(`type == 'birth'`) and this is his `single_type_event` (first case of the results from above). This `person_1` also has a record that he started  school(`type == 'enrollment'`), but he doesn't have a record of graduation. This is his `paired_type_event_1` (second case of the results). If this person had a graduation record (`type == 'graduation'`) then it would have been presented in the same row with the enrollment record. Assuming that this table is actually a paper record book for the `town_a` these records should be organized in the following order: born (a single row) -> enrolled (another row) (born (a single row) -> enrolled+graduated (another single row) for a person who graduated)

I know that it looks like a mess and I have some solid doubts about this, but if it's possible to achieve in SQLAlchemy or using raw SQL I would be very thankful for the guidance!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely followed the requirement, but assuming that 'event types' are unique within an 'event group' (that is, the 'event group' binds the single event and the paired events) ...

The idea is to start with a list of all event groups and targets (allGroups), then match to it when data of the various types is available (left joins)

```
;with allGroups as 
(
    select distinct eventGroup, eventTarget 
    from SomeEvent
    where ???
)
select ag.eventGroup, ag.eventTarget, type1 = e1.eventType, type2 = e2.eventType, type3 = e3.eventType
    , createDate = case when e1.createDate is not null then e1.createDate
                        when e2.createDate is not null then e2.createDate
                        when e3.createDate is not null then e3.createDate
                        else null
                    end
from allGroups ag
left join SomeEvent e1 on ag.eventTarget = e1.eventTarget and ag.eventGroup = e1.eventGroup and e2.eventType = 'type_1'
left join SomeEvent e2 on ag.eventTarget = e2.eventTarget and ag.eventGroup = e2.eventGroup and e2.eventType = 'type_2'
left join SomeEvent e3 on ag.eventTarget = e3.eventTarget and ag.eventGroup = e3.eventGroup and e3.eventType = 'type_3'
order by createDate
```

If you can't do CTE's (Common Table Expressions) on your platform, you can do the initial select into a temp table, table variable, etc.

Hopefully this will get you thinking.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Although I'm not sure that I've managed to present my issue clearly enough, so I've added an example with the paper record book